# How to implement moving/animated infographics in an ionic application?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, animation, css-animations

I want to create custom infographics for my ionic application, something like you see under:
https://in.pinterest.com/pin/10203536643808929/

Any suggestions on what tool I can use to create such infographics or any specific implementation strategy I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Not adding entire implementation, but this would point you in a right direction:

You can implement the infographics using `ion-slides`. Place the info. in each slide. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides.

```
<ion-slides pager="false" >
        <ion-slide>
          <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <h1>Slide 3</h1>
        </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

For animated background, you need to keep the content of the slides transparent & add some background animation to the container div